# How to hash a Tezos public key

Tags: hash, offline

I need to create a Tezos public key hash based on a public `ed25519` key only.

I am aware of an utility that generates entire keystore based on mnemonics - this is not what I need.

I'd welcome either a step by step description how to get from an `edpk` to a `tz1` form or a code snippet.

Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

Heres how to do it in python, where the variable `pubkey` is the bytes array of the public key

```
P2HASH_MAGIC = bytes.fromhex('06a1a4')
blake2bhash = blake2b(pubkey, digest_size=20).digest()
shabytes = sha256(sha256(P2HASH_MAGIC + blake2bhash).digest()).digest()[:4]
pkhash = b58encode(P2HASH_MAGIC + blake2bhash + shabytes).decode()
```

Comment: Thanks, that's great. Would you mind to improve that answer by adding comments explaining what happens there? For example - what is P2HASH_MAGIC and why do we cut out some bytes in line 3.

Comment: Input for b58encode is going to be 51 bytes long (`P2HASH_MAGIC` is 3 bytes, `blake2bhash` is 20 bytes `shabytes` is  32 - 4 = 28 bytes) . This is going to produce a 49-char long `base58check` string. However, a `tz1` address is 36-char long. Surely, this method is not correct, is it?

Answer (score 5):

Do you have the tezos repo built? If yes, you can run the ocaml CLI with tezos-crypto:

```
 $ dune utop src/lib_crypto
```

and then:

```
ocaml# open Tezos_crypto;;
ocaml# Ed25519.Public_key.of_b58check_exn
           "edpkuoK2J2UVbDcSTdJgP85JmDN3gxBCswcgApbtY5d7zHVunwCKNR"
       |> Ed25519.Public_key.hash
       |> Ed25519.Public_key_hash.to_b58check;;                                                                                                                                                      
- : string = "tz1L1bypLzuxGHmx3d6bHFJ2WCi4ZDbocSCA"
```

Comment: While this is probably a good answer, it is not helpful in my case. I need to do it programatically, in a nodejs app.

Answer (score 4):

In python, using the git version of [pytezos](https://github.com/murbard/pytezos#crypto-keys-and-signatures):

```
from pytezos.crypto import Key

public_key = 'edpkuoK2J2UVbDcSTdJgP85JmDN3gxBCswcgApbtY5d7zHVunwCKNR'
hash = Key(public_key).public_key_hash()
print(hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

In NodeJS it is also possible to do it using `sotez`:

```
import {Key} from 'sotez';

const sotezKey = new Key({ key: 'edpktx799pgw7M4z8551URER52VcENNCSZwE9f9cst4v6h5vCrQmJE' });
await sotezKey.ready;
console.log(sotezKey.publicKeyHash());
```

prints:
`tz1Xv78KMT7cHyVDLi9RmQP1KuWULHDafZdK`