# How to get address from publicKey?

Tags: address, public-key

I have a Tezos **public key** and I want to generate a **Tezos address** (tz...) from this public key.
I want to do this with Dart language inside the **Flutter** framework.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert ed25519 bytes to Tezos public key](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-to-convert-ed25519-bytes-to-tezos-public-key)

Comment: There are many posts here about converting keys to/from the different formats. A quick search:
https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-to-convert-ed25519-bytes-to-tezos-public-key
https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-hash-a-tezos-public-key

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example implemented in `Dart`: https://github.com/Tezsure/tezos_dart/blob/master/lib/helper/generateKeys.dart#L7