# How to get Tezos KT and TZ address from Public Key

Tags: node, public-key

Is there a way to convert Tezos Blockchain Public Key to address using any python/ go / nodejs libraries

Below are the sample public keys which i am trying to convert into Address.

Input public key - 6564706b7647704d6d387246517838655a376a61714b346a735771506879326a366e32394e756d485a315a3774597139664758583947 output

Address - tz1RoqRN77gGpeV96vEXzt62Sns2LViZiUCa

Input public key 2 - 6564706b75706673506e4c6169517866594454694163536756365569686661463537516e7068555551746943364d35384b3868356662 output

address 2 - KT1XhyBEdy8YrE6XjyX6zSTMj6rjFdnjh5NV

Comment: There are Tezos libraries for each of those languages, that all interact with or create keys, and convert them into addresses. All can easily be found via google (e.g. PyTezos, GoTezos, Taquito). Have you looked into any of these yet? It would also be helpful to explain your usecase more, like where did these PK's come from, there may be better/easier ways to do what you are trying to do

Comment: @SimonMcLoughlin i checked but did not find any suitable methods to pass public key and get address.

Answer (score 0):

This seemed to have already been answered. See:

- [How to convert ed25519 bytes to Tezos public key](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2024/how-to-convert-ed25519-bytes-to-tezos-public-key)
- [Understanding base58check encoding of a Tezos public key](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2060/understanding-base58check-encoding-of-a-tezos-public-key?rq=1)
- [How to hash a Tezos public key](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/2016/how-to-hash-a-tezos-public-key)

Also, KT1 addresses aren't linked to any public key.